# Android development - online course. [Reference request]

Tags: android

I want to start with Android applications development.

I'm very familiar with Computer application languages (Mainly Java, C++, C#, C , Assembly, Php, but some more).

I'm here to request reference for online android development courses in video, such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=EL-dXvv1sF3mg) course.

Any additional Android course in this style, will be welcomed.

thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to go to [this](http://www.oreilly.com/) site and select Android link which is [this](http://shop.oreilly.com/category/browse-subjects/programming/android-programming.do) and then select the book you want and copy the whole name of the book and go to google and type

```
thebookname ext:pdf
```

this will show the pdfs and download the original file.This will save your money and time because shipping takes time...

and believe me you will find **97%** of the books listed on orielly...

and i think the books from oreilly are **very good.**

and for begining you should download [this](http://thepiratebay.tn/torrent/6484031/Wrox.Professional.Android.2.Application.Development.Mar.2010.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I got started with the [Android Cookbook](http://androidcookbook.com/home.seam), which is, by their byline "A Crowd-sourced Cookbook on Writing Great Android® Apps"

It has several tutorials that are explained quite well - always handy to refer to the Developers Guide or here (SO), just in case something is not clear.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It that source have a video tutorials, or only text tutorial?

Comment: Just text, but a good thing is, the tutes are only a page or two each.